# count the row affected put in Log File through batch file

Tags: sql, batch-file, cmd, sqlcmd, logfile

I bet this is just too simple but i can't put it together:

how to count the row affected put it in a Log File while using batch file on running the script.

xxx_proc.bat

```
@echo off 

echo Running script in THENW

echo %DATE% tprdcr.sql executed > Logfile.txt

isql -UEMXXX2 -PEMXXX2 -SKXXXXXXDB02 -Jcp8x50 -w20x00 -itprdcr.sql >> Logfile.txt

echo tprdcr.sql Generated successfully

pause

EXIT /B
```

LogFile.txt

[image]

The result is quite many, so i just want it to display **[nn rows affected]**. Also if there will be error in one update statement it will just bypass the count and display the error.

Comment: Start with `for /F "tokens=*" %G in ('type Logfile.txt') do @echo "%G"` from command line (to run in a '.bat' batch you should double all `%` sign: use `%%G`). Then you can refine the result filtering source by e.g. '^| find' or sum rows affected counts etc. Feel free to update your question with actual achievements and ask more in case you crane at something. [Read more ...](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there is something you could do with your .sql files to modify the output to make your life easier. But if you want to work with the log files as they are now...

Until you show what the errors look like, we can't suggest how to bypass on error.

Here is a pure batch method to get the total count:

```
set /a cnt=0
for /f "delims=( " %%N in (
  'findstr  /c:"^(1 row affected)" /c:"^([0-9][0-9]* rows affected)" "Logfile.txt"'
) do set /a cnt+=%%N
echo %%N rows affected
```

You could also use my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044):

```
jrepl "\((\d+) rows? affected\)" "total+=Number($1);false" /jmatch /jbeg "total=0" /jend "output.WriteLine(total+' rows affected')" /f "Logfile.txt"
```

You can put the above command in a FOR /F loop if you need to capture the total in a variable:

```
for /f %%N in (
  'jrepl "\((\d+) rows? affected\)" "total+=Number($1);false" /jmatch /jbeg "total=0" /jend "output.WriteLine(total+' rows affected')" /f "Logfile.txt"'
) do set total=%%N
echo %total%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the original Logfile to remain intact, then you could use this:

```
@echo off
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::Other code here

set count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%r in ('type Logfile.txt ^| findstr /i "row affected"') do (
for /f "tokens=1 delims=^( " %%c in ("%%r") do set /a count+=%%c
)
echo Total rows affected: !count!
echo Total rows affected: !count!>>Logfile.txt
pause
exit /b
```

Optionally, if you want to bypass writing each individual row affected to the log file, and just write a single line stating the number of rows affected, you might could use this instead:

```
@echo off
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::Other code here

set count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%r in ('isql -UEMXXX2 -PEMXXX2 -SKXXXXXXDB02 -Jcp8x50 -w20x00 -itprdcr.sql ^| findstr /i "row affected)"') do (
for /f "tokens=1 delims=^( " %%c in ("%%r") do set /a count+=%%c
)
echo Total rows affected: !count!
echo Total rows affected: !count!>>Logfile.txt
pause
exit /b
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why two FOR /F loops? Even though it's not shown in the OP's example, you probably need to account for something like `(10 rows affected)` in the log file. The plural will not match your FINDSTR search string.

Comment: @Ketsuban Thank you. It works as i expected, i uses the second one but both works well.

Comment: Doh - I forgot you didn't use  the `/c` option, so it searches for any line that contains "row" ***or*** "affected". But that may not be good, depending on what other text may appear in the log.